# How to continuously copy new S3 files to another S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

How can I continuously copy one S3 bucket to another? I want to copy the files every time a new file has been added.

I've tried using the boto3 copy_object however I require the key each time which won't work if I'm getting a new file each time.

Comment: See [Replicating Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html). Don't build this yourself, if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Replicating objects - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html):

> To automatically replicate new objects as they are written to the bucket **use live replication**, such as Same-Region Replication (SRR) or Cross-Region Replication (CRR).

S3 Replication will automatically create new objects in another bucket as soon as they are created. (Well, it can take a few seconds.)

Alternatively, you could configure the S3 bucket to **trigger an AWS Lambda function** that uses the `CopyObject()` command to copy the object to another location. This method is useful if you want to **selectively copy files**, by having the Lambda function perform some logic before performing the copy (such as checking the file type).

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/

You can use the aws cli s3 sync command to achieve this.